# Modal Vs Modeless Dialogs

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, modeless

I'm having two forms namely `One` and `Two` , and the title text of both are same as their names.

`One` is having a button and the click event of it contains,

```
Two l_objTwo = new Two();
l_objTwo.Show();            
MessageBox.Show("Two Closed");
```

It opens the `Two` and after that the "Two Closed" message will be popped up.

My scenerio is, that `Two` should be opened in a `Modeless` way i.e i need the control of `One` and at the same time i need to execute some functionality after `Two` got closed. As of now I'm using like,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);

Two l_objTwo = new Two();
l_objTwo.Show();
IntPtr l_objHandle = FindWindow(null, "Two");
while ((int)l_objHandle > 0)
{
    l_objHandle = FindWindow(null, "Two");
    Application.DoEvents();
}
MessageBox.Show("Two Closed");
```

Its working fine, but is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: @svick & @ Jodrell : Thank you...........

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the only way.
Your first form will attach a handler to either `FormClosed` or `FormClosing` public events of the second form.

When your second form closes it will raise the event and the first form will know that your second form is closed.

Just use this snippet:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(FormClosedHandler);
        f.Show();
    }
  void FormClosedHandler(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Second form has closed.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an event handler

```
var two = new Two();
two.Closed += OnTwoClosed;
two.Show();

private void OnTwoClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Two Closed")
}
```

Haven't tested this code on a winforms `Form` but the principal is the same, and easier than using the Windows API with all its inherent pitfalls.

Another benefit is, the titles of the windows can be whatever you like.

[After checking here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) it appears both `Closed` and `FormClosed` are valid events.

Answer (score 0):

This looks all around messy. Not sure what you want to achieve here. Just open form two in One's event handler and hook two's onclose-event to your MessageBox.